How to get Startup apps in .NET? Windows 10, 11
How to get startup apps in .NET?
CurrentUser LocalMachine SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
I got the startup apps from here but didn't get the expected result because I had 19 startup apps from my computer, I need all startup apps.

To get all startup applications in a .NET application, you need to query multiple sources. The registry key you mentioned (SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) only covers a portion of startup applications.

another portions of startup is in shell:startup. Start->run enter shell:startup and it will open startup folder.

There are planty of similar questions on StackOverflow and the programming language is not very relevant here. But none of them is canonical or comprehensive enough. I found this post on reddit, it lists many options and should give you an idea of how complex this task is. I would expect that something in Windows (e.g. WMI?) does all job, but no guarantee.

Windows has multiple directories and registry keys where programs launch on startup:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run - where programs specific to the current user launch on startup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run - where programs launch at startup system-wide for all users
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce - similar to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ ... \Run, except programs only run once and remove the entry on next logon
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce - similar to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ ... \Run, except programs only run once and remove the entry on next logon
There are also these directories:
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup - startup programs that run at startup system-wide for all users
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup - startup programs that run at startup for the current user only
We have to query registry values and get files from ...Programs\Startup directories.
Example:
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public static class StartupApps
{
    private static readonly string[] s_startupRegKeys =
    [
        @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",
        @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce",
        @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",
        @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
    ];

    private static IEnumerable<string> ReadRegSzValues(string keyPath)
    {
        string actualKey =
            keyPath.Contains("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")
            ? keyPath.Split(["HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"], StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
            : keyPath.Split(["HKEY_CURRENT_USER"], StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        bool usesLocalMachine = keyPath.Contains("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE");
        RegistryKey? key =
            usesLocalMachine
            ? Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(actualKey)
            : Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(actualKey);

        if (key == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (string valueName in key.GetValueNames())
        {
            object value = key.GetValue(valueName);

            if (value is string stringValue)
            {
                yield return stringValue;
            }
        }

        key.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return startup apps stored in the Windows registry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of startup apps from Windows registry.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStartupAppsFromRegistry()
    {
        foreach (string key in s_startupRegKeys)
        {
            foreach (string regKey in ReadRegSzValues(key))
            {
                yield return regKey;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStartupAppsFromStartupDirectory()
    {
        foreach (string startupObject in Directory.GetFiles(GetCurrentUserStartupDirectory()))
        {
            yield return startupObject;
        }
        foreach (string startupObject in Directory.GetFiles(GetSystemWideStartupDirectory()))
        {
            yield return startupObject;
        }
    }

    private static string GetCurrentUserStartupDirectory()
    {
        string? appData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA");
        if (appData is null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No APPDATA variable was found. Make sure the operating system is Windows.");
        }
        return Path.Combine(appData, "Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs");
    }

    private static string GetSystemWideStartupDirectory()
    {
        string? programData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSPROFILE")
            ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMDATA");
        if (programData is null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No ALLUSERSPROFILE or PROGRAMDATA variable was found. Make sure the operating system is Windows.");
        }
        return Path.Combine(programData, "Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs");
    }
}

Use it like so:
IEnumerable<string> startupObjects1 = StartupObjects.GetStartupAppsFromStartupDirectory();
IEnumerable<string> startupObjects2 = StartupObjects.GetStartupAppsFromRegistry();

